# What JS obfuscation used?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Do you guys have any idea what kind of JS obfuscation is used?

#### Decoder:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function a(data){
  return unescape(atob(data));
}
</script>
```

#### Obfuscated:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(a('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'))</script>
```

#### DEMO:

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cunefiwiti

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 4):

[`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) is base64 encoding. You can reverse it with [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa).

Addtionally running `btoa` on the content seems to produce a uri-encoded string. That is kinda silly.

The result is:

```
 <iframe id='movie' class='embed-responsive-item' allowfullscreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true' src='[kind dangerous looking url]' frameborder='0' seamless></iframe>
```

Used: `decodeURIComponent(atob(string));`

Comment: already tried it. result is diffrent. that is why i am asking :)

Comment: What do you mean _"result is different"_?

Comment: i guess u didn't tried and look at the code. please review before down voting my question. don't simply decode it, that's simple ofcourse if you just decode. but review.

Comment: i still didn't get the right answer. i ask what kind of obfuscation is used, but it only answers to reverse the code which is NOT the answer.

Comment: if u reverse the result of `unescape(atob(data))` the result is diffrent from the original encryption.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. This is JavaScript, what does php have to do with it? I didn't downvote your question. There is no encryption or obfuscation involved. It's just encoding. The goal of encoding is transmission not security. Can you show what you mean by _'different'_?

Answer (score 0):

#### After severals hands-on, I got my own answer.

```
<?php
function mb_rawurlencode($url){
    $encoded='';
    $length=mb_strlen($url);
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
    $encoded.='%'.wordwrap(bin2hex(mb_substr($url,$i,1)),2,'%',true);
    }
    return $encoded;
}

function jso_encode($data) {
    return base64_encode(mb_rawurlencode($data));
}
?>
```

#### example usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <script>
    function a(data){
        return unescape(atob(data));
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>document.write(a('<?php echo jso_encode("code_goes_here");?>'));</script>
    </body>
</html>
```